# remove all items in array that start with a particular string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hi let's say that I have an array like this in javascript:

```
var arr = ["ftp_text_1", "abc_text_2", "ftp_text_3"];
```

How do I remove from all the strings from my array that start with `ftp_`

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simply use **[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**:

```
arr = arr.filter(function (item) {
   return item.indexOf("ftp_") !== 0;
});
```

**Edit:** for IE9- support you may use [**jQuery.grep**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/):

```
arr = $.grep(arr, function (item) {
   return item.indexOf("ftp_") !== 0;
});
```

Comment: That returns all items that do not start with ftp.

Comment: The check is whether or not `'ftp'` is at position `0`, i.e. at the start of the string. +1

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression:

```
$.each(arr, function (index, value) {
    if (value.match("^ftp_")) {
        arr.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Note: This is a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 1):

The index position of the element shifts up as a element is deleted from the list hence some elements may not delete from the list.

So the best practice is to delete the list from the end .

```
for(var i=arr.length-1 ; i>=0;i--){
   if(arr[i].includes("ftp_"){
      arr.splice(i, 1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use array **filter method** and string **includes method** to filter the specific string in the following way.

```js
console.log(['US-1', 'UK-1'].filter(d => !d.includes('UK-')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use temp array to store your required string.

```
for(i=0;i&lt;are.length;i+=) {
  if(!arr[i].startesWith('ftp_')){
    temp[j]=arr[i];
    j++:
  }
  arr=temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A mix of [**Array.filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [**String.startsWith**](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) (which seems to be **a bit more human understandable** to me)

One liner with **ES6**

```js
arr = arr.filter(item => !item.startsWith("ftp_"));
```

otherwise :

```js
arr = arr.filter(function (item) {
   return !item.startsWith("ftp_"));
}
```

This is of course if you're ok to put IE on the side (but it now represents 0.56% of the web, maybe we can start not talking of it anymore)