# Javascript - delete array items by value LIKE

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this simple array

```
var array = ['x.89999', 'y.sisisis', 'x.585858'];
```

I want to remove all the items in the array starting by 'x.' so to return this array:

```
['y.sisisis']
```

How can i do this without having to loop or iterate all the entire array? (i know it's probably not possible so don't mind if not possible)

Is there some builtin / native code i can use?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `.filter()`, but that still loops internally.

Comment: Using regex is the obvious and probably the only answer, but you have to iterate over the elements in the array to do that. Or use `.filter` but that iterates over the array too.

Comment: If you ensure the list is always sorted, you only have to iterate it until you encounter the first string that doesn't start with x.

Comment: Take a look in older post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954438/remove-item-from-array-by-value

Comment: Sorry I posted a wrong link this may help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518855/remove-all-items-in-array-that-start-with-a-particular-string

Comment: Let me get this straight. You want to eliminate all items that start with `x.`, but do so without actually looking at each item. Perhaps you could investigate quantum computing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may use `array.filter()`

```
var newArray = array.filter(function(item){
    return item.indexOf('x.') !== 1;
});
```

there is no way to do this job without looping through the whole array.
The only case – array is sorted alphabetically. But sorting demands looping through too

Comment: This loops over the entire collection.

Comment: hey, read text below code, i mentioned that

Comment: It's still not correct. Depending on where the data comes from and if data is added afterwards, you don't have to loop over everything.

Comment: I'll wait a little more, maybe someone is going to post some other solution, atm thanks a lot @KaterinaTort

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the items to be removed will *always* precede the other items alphabetically (ie `x` is before `y`), you can sort your array and then break the loop as soon as the non-x value has been found:

```
function filter(arr) {
    arr.sort();
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (arr[i][0] !== 'x') {
            break;
        }
    }
    return arr.slice(i);
}

filter(arr); // logs: "Iterated to 5 of array length 9"
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xomqjuxb/1/)

Of course, as JazzCat mentions, this is no good if you only have one `y` value and it's right at the end of the array - you're still going to have to iterate over the whole array.

Comment: cooool a lot cooool ................

Answer (score 1):

Alternate option is to use regular expression, something like this. Fix your regex according to your requirement.

```
var array = ['x.89999', 'y.sisisis', 'x.585858'];

var filtArr = array.filter(function(x){
    return x.match("^[x].+$");
});

console.log(filtArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

One different answer not using explicit iteration or Array.prototype.filter:

```
var array = ['x.89999', 'y.sisisis', 'x.585858'];
array = array.join("#").replace(/(#?x\.\w*)/g,"").replace(/^#/,"").split("#");
//["y.sisisis"]
```

Of course you will need to take care of the separator character.

The good point is that it works on old browsers (ie8) while Array.prototype.filter does not.