# How can I ignore filenames starts with dot using JS?

Tags: javascript, regex, filenames

Consider I've a directory "Data" with 3 files: "One", "Two", ".Three".
How should I change this code to fill array "samples" only filenames which doesn't start with "."? In this example, it'll be "One" and "Two" files.

Thanks!

```
var samples = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Data.listing.length; i++) {
    var file = Data.listing[i];
  }
return {"outfiles": samples};
```

Comment: Also, probably a duplicate of [remove all items in array that start with a particular string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518855/remove-all-items-in-array-that-start-with-a-particular-string).

Answer (score 1):

Simply filter it using `f => !f.startsWith('.')`.

```js
let files = ["One", "Two", ".Three"];

console.log(files.filter(f => !f.startsWith('.')))
```